# How best to stream data to an IP address?

Tags: python, linux, streaming, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I'm working on a beaglebone (read: Angstrom Linux) and have a bunch of data that I'm capturing in a python script.

I'd like to stream that data in a graphical format to an internal IP address. I've streamed data before using matplotlib, but on the same machine. I've also set up a webserver on the beaglebone, but I have only been able to read index.html

The most straightforward way, with my limited knowledge, would be to have index.html render an image of the graph, then just refresh the page and rewrite the image very quickly... but that sucks and I know it.

Would I be best off packing the images into a video and streaming that? Could html5 pick up on that video? Is there a better way?

Ideally my streaming would be fairly close to real-time. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: its not that clear what you are trying to do. just to clarify , you are running a python script on a beagleboard and want to stream the data to a PC?  are you trying to stream to a web browser or can you write your own client?

Comment: You can't _"stream that data in a graphical format"_ -- data is just bits regardless of whether it's text, a video or an image.  Rather than describing the implementation, tell us what should happen from the user's point of view.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. The user should be able to, from somewhere else on the network, be able to access a near real-time (less than 1s delay) plot of a parameter that is being calculated within a python script running on the beagleboard.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris: Have you tried using event based networking frameworks like Twisted ? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted